# Can I install and run multiple versions of gcloud (google cloud sdk) on the same machine?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-sdk, gcloud-cli

Features and options in gcloud are sometimes deprecated/removed. If CI depends on it and refactoring is not an option while at the same time we need to use new features which come out in later releases can we have multiple versions of gcloud installed on same machines and used concurrently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways to install Cloud SDK on your machine. For this probably simplest would be to download versioned package from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#versioned.

For example you can do

```
gsutil cp gs://cloud-sdk-release/google-cloud-sdk-VERSION-linux-x86_64.tar.gz .
```

where `VERSION` is you want to get (for example "161.0.0"). You could also use `wget` or `curl` or simply use [browser to download](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/downloads#versioned) the package for your platform.

Then unzip/untar into your desired location for example

```
mkdir -p ~/cloudsdk/161.0.0
tar xzf google-cloud-sdk-161.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz -C ~/cloudsdk/161.0.0
```

repeat for some different version:

```
mkdir -p ~/cloudsdk/130.0.0
tar xzf google-cloud-sdk-130.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz -C ~/cloudsdk/130.0.0
```

Now you can run gcloud via

```
~/cloudsdk/161.0.0/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud components list
```

or

```
~/cloudsdk/130.0.0/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud components list
```

Note both version will share same config directory. This is generally undesirable, because there could have been changes between versions in how they treat configuration. To force different Cloud SDK versions use different gcloud configurations set `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG` environment variable to point to different gcloud config directory. For example:

```
$ CLOUDSDK_CONFIG=~/.config/gcloud-legacy ~/cloudsdk/130.0.0/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud
```